# JQTouch transition problem

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I have a problem with the jqtouch bottom toolbar. Its a stationary bottom toolbar that is implemented with the iScroll plugin for jqtouch.

When I want to switch between a page with a "right" slide transition effect I want to exclude the bottombar from also using the transition effect. 
The reason for this is because it looks weird when the bottom toolbar slides to the right.

edit:
Example would be to imitate the iPhone webbrowser. You always see the navigation at the bottom and it does not move with the website. 
This effect I want within jqtouch.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a new update in jqtouch.